# Move Text from cell to text label in a different view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have created an app that displays 10 random numbers in a table view. This is the code I used

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShowNumber", for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1): \(Int(arc4random_uniform(10001)))"

    return cell
}
```

Now I want to be able to click on one cell and be taken to another view controller and in the center of the page it displays the random number. I have the view controller all set up and linked to the original table view. I'm just having trouble passing my data through the segue. This is what I have so far. I know it unfinished, I just don't know what to do.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {   
    if segue.identifier == "showRandomNumber" {
        let controller = segue.destination as! ShowNumberTableViewController
        let selectedRow = (tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow as NSIndexPath?)?.row ?? 0
        controller.LabelText = 
    }
```

The LabelText is the name of the label that I want to pass the data to, but I don't know how to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `indexPathForSelectedRow`, you can get a reference to the cell that triggered the segue. You can then access the textLabel within that cell, get its value, and pass it to the next view controller.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {   
    if segue.identifier == "showRandomNumber" {
        let controller = segue.destination as! ShowNumberTableViewController
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            if let textToPass = cell.textLabel.text {
                controller.labelText = textToPass
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `ShowNumberTableViewController` you want a `var labelText` and in your `viewDidLoad()` you can assign it to the textLabel in that view controller with

```
centerLabel.text = labelText
```

Comment: It shows an error saying use of undeclared type 'ShowNumber'. ShowNumber is the name of my custom cell. Do I need to declare it somewhere?

Comment: @TylerMiddleton It was an example based on your code. Do you have a custom class for your cell?

Comment: @TylerMiddleton if not, just change it to as! UITableViewCell

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing, the numbers will change when you scroll the table view. I think you should save the numbers in an array.

About how to grab the selected number in the `prepareForSegue:` I would do this way:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showRandomNumber" {
        if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell, indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
            let selectedNumber = numbers[indexPath.row]
            controller.labelText = String(selectedNumber)
        }
    }
}
```